# Interaction between hash value and `<<` operator

Tags: ruby, hash

I expected:

```
h = Hash.new([])
h['a'] << 'b'
h['a'] << 'c'
h # => {}
```

to give `{'a' => ['b','c']}`, not an empty hash.

I also found out that the insert operation targets the default value, because after the code above it is euqal to `['b','c']`:

```
h.default # => ['b','c']
```

I am looking for an explanation on why it does not work and how to do it optimally so it works.

Comment: Tested, appeared strange, update if you get it in details.

Comment: What details do you need? It is already strange ...

Comment: clarification for above strange thing :)

Comment: Well I quess that it is what the answers are for ;)

Comment: The default value is just that a default return value when the key does not exist. It has nothing to do with key value assignment. @SergioTulentsev has shown you how to "do it so it works"

Comment: Another way that is commonly done: `h = {}; (h['a'] ||= []) << 'b'; h #=> {'a'=>['b']}; (h['a'] ||= []) << 'c'; h #=> {'a'=>['b', 'c'])`. Initially `h.key('a') #=> false`, so `(h['a'] ||= []) << 'b' #=> (h['a'] = h['a] || []) << 'b' #=> (h['a'] = nil || []) << 'b' #=> (h['a'] = []) << 'b' #=> h['a'] << 'b'; h #=> {'a'=>['b']`.

Comment: What does not work? How to do what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why your line didn't work is that [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Hash.html), upon accessing a missing key, simply returns the default value (whatever you specified), without assigning it to the key. And since your default value is a complex mutable object (and it's the very same object that is returned every time), you get what you observed: all values are shoveled straight into the default value, bypassing the hash. This is probably the most common mistake with hashes and mutable default values.

To do what you want, use the third form of Hash.new

```
new {|hash, key| block } → new_hash
```

like this, for example

```
h = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = [] }
```

Comment: but we passed `[]` as an argument for new not as a block code. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @ray: yeah, that form of setting default value doesn't work as "expected" with mutable objects (array here)

Comment: @SergioTulentsevI have elaborated the answer so it is more usefull for other people, please do corrections if you feel so inclined.

Comment: The [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Hash.html#method-c-new) explicitly state: _"It is the block's responsibility to store the value in the hash if required."_

Comment: @Stefan you are right, althought is seems to be more connected to the "block" style.

Comment: @gorn the documentation for `Hash.new` gets more specific: with a positional argument, i.e. `Hash.new([])` you get a single default object. With a block argument, i.e. `Hash.new { [] }` you do get multiple copies, but they are not persisted. Only with `Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }` you get one copy per key. So yes, it is connected to the block style because a block is required to get this mechanism working. Without a block, the default value is simply returned and no keys are being set.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It was tedious but I got it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you modify this specific object you passed as a default value. So:

```
h = Hash.new([])
h['a'] << 'b'
h['a'] << 'c'
h['b'] # or h['a'] or h[:virtually_anything]
# => ["b", "c"]
```

Comment: I thought that `array << x` is something like `array = array + [x]`

Comment: @gorn: no, it's not.

Comment: Well, obviously it is not, but according to documentation << "Pushes the given object on to the end of this array." So how it differs from `array = array + [x]` (which also places x as last element of array).

Comment: @gorn: "which also places x as last element of array)" - not quite. It creates a __new__ array, rather than modifying the existing one in-place.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `h` has no key `'a'`, you need to initialize it before or it's just a default value reset:

```
h = Hash.new([])
h['a'] = ['b']
h['a'] << 'c'

h['a'] #=> ["b", "c"]
h #=> {"a"=>["b", "c"]}
```

This behave the same:

```
k = Hash.new
k.default = []
```

While, as explained by Sergio Tulentsev, (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53614695/5239030) this creates the key "on the fly", try this:

```
k = Hash.new {|h, k| puts "Just created a new key: #{k}"; h[k] = [] }
p k['a'] << 'a'
p k['a'] << 'a'
p k['b'] << 'b'
p k
```

Comment: Should not `array << 'b'` be identical to `array= ['b']` on empty arrays?

Comment: I.e. should not `h['a'] << 'b'` behave like `h['a'] = ['b']` if `h['a']` is empty array?

Comment: No, there's no reason for it to behave this way. It's all about what object are you currently modifying. When you're doing `h['a'] = ['b']`, you're creating a new `Array` object and assign it to `'a'` key in `h` `Hash`.

Comment: If you look at  http://tpcg.io/UBS8FQ  than you see the reason. For an empty array it behaves identically.

Comment: You say "It's because h has no key 'a', you need to initialize it" but is not the default value supposed to do that automagically?

Comment: @gorn: "but is not the default value supposed to do that automagically?" - one could argue that this would be a sensible approach. Alas, wording in Hash documentation is pretty unambiguous. "Retrieves the value object corresponding to the key object. If not found, returns the default value"

Comment: If the `h['a'] += ['b']` would not work as well than I would not complain, but to me `array << 'b'` and `array += ['b']` looks very identical

Comment: @gorn: well, that's your misunderstanding of how these two work. The latter _reassigns_ array. That's the key difference.

Comment: @gorn JFYI, you should `@mention` people to whom you're responding. Or they may never see your comments.

Comment: @gorn, Sergio Tulentsev already gave a great explanation, I just added an edit to my post based on it.

Comment: @gorn `h['a']` and `h['a']=` are two different methods. The [former](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) returns the value for key `'a'` (which might be the default value) whereas the [latter](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) assigns a new value to key `'a'`. If you call `h['a'] += ['b']` it is equivalent to `h['a'] = h['a'] + ['b']`, i.e. you retrieve the default value for `'a'` (empty array), concatenate `['b']` and assign the result to the key `'a'` (which then exists).